# I am given a $3$D vector $v=[x,y,z]$ and an amount I want to move it, by some constant say $c=5.$

Tags: vectors, 3d, orientation

Say I am given a 3D vector $v = [x,y,z]$ and an amount I want to move it, some constant say $c = 5$. I would like to move the vector in the direction it is pointing (or oriented).

Is there a simple equation for doing this?

Originally I thought one could just do $[x+c, y+c, z+c]$ but ostensibly this would move the vector regardless of its orientation. I want to move it only relative to the orientation, the place it is pointing.

Comment: vectors are defined by their magnitude and direction, not where in the plane they are located.  In other words, if I move a vector, it is still the same vector.

Comment: Sure it's still the same vector but where the vector is located is different?

Comment: I think you're confusing position and direction of movement. Suppose you have a vector valued function $r(t)$, i.e. a function which gives a point in space. So maybe at time $t= 1$, we have $r(1)= (-1, 2, 0)$. If you want to move in the direction of the vector $v$ at time $t= 1$, e.g. $v(1)= (6,3,-2)$, then you want $r(1) + v(1)= (-1+6,2+3,0-2)= (5,5,-2)$. Generally, you may not want a "full step" in the direction of $v$ or may want even more of a 'step.' You want $r(t) + c v(t)$, where $c > 0$ is some step size in the $v$-direction. Generally, I suppose you want this done recursively.

Comment: @mathematics2x2life okay, so if I had some position r(t) where at r(1) the position is (0,0,0) and I had a vector v(t) where at v(1) = (1,0,0), then it's as simple as adding them. r(1) + v(1) = (1,0,0). And in doing so I have moved in the direction of the vector. But say I wanted to move in a set amount say c = 5. Would it then be 5(r(1) + v(1)) = (5,0,0)? Would this make sense? Thanks for the help btw. If you respond as a answer I can give you a check mark. This really clears things up.

Comment: Assume that $A$ is the starting point of the vector (it seems you need to respect it). If you want to "move a vector in its own direction and orientation", simply add the corresponding multiple of the vector to it: $A+kv$ will do the job, $k$ is the constant you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that what you're looking for is how to move the point in a plane, that your vector is pointing at in relation to the origin of your coordinate system:

You have to add your vector plus a vector in the same direction with length $c=5$

$$\vec{r_{new}} = \vec{r_{old}} + c\cdot\vec{e_r} = \left(\begin{matrix}
r_x \\
r_y \\
r_z \\
\end{matrix}\right) + c\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{r_x^2 + r_y^2 + r_z^2}}\cdot\left(\begin{matrix}
r_x \\
r_y \\
r_z \\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

Here, $\vec{e_r}$ is called the unity vector (length 1) in direction of $\vec{r}$, which is how it's normally used. The trick is that the length of the vector you multiply $c$ by, has to have length 1. If you're not sure how that works, just try to calculate the length of $\vec{e_r}$.

Also, in physics and maths, when you use a vector to describe the location of a point in a coordinate system, you usually use the letter $r$, as in the *radius* from the origin.

Comment: To clarify, $\vec{e_r}$ is equal to the original vector? I.e. all the values $r_x$, $r_y$, $r_z$ are the same as in the original vector?

Comment: $\vec{e}_v$ is the original vector normalized, in other words the original vector divided by it’s total length. The resulting vector preserves the direction of the original one, but has length 1. By multiplying that resulting vector by a constant $c$, you get a vector with length $c$ but the direction of the original one.